# SQL timestamp for event constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, timestamp, constraints

I have a task to create a trigger which are supposed to check a constraint for an assignment in database design. The trigger is supposed to check if a new event will fit into the current schedule. Two events cannot take place at the same time. Attributes are date, time and length (time) of the event. Right now I am thinking of checking the interval values for time + length in events with the new event's time + length. If they overlap it will raise an exception. My problem is that I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: We are using postgres.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can do that easily with an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#ddl-constraints-exclusion), no trigger required.

Assuming your table looks something like this:

```
create table event 
(
   id serial primary key, 
   event_name varchar(100), 
   event_start timestamp, 
   duration interval
);
```

Then you can prevent overlapping events using the following constraint:

```
alter table event
  add constraint no_overlapping_events
  exclude using gist (tsrange(event_start, event_start + duration) with &&);
```

The `tsrange()` in the constraint definition creates a [timestamp range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) that can efficiently be compared for overlapping rows.

The following two inserts will succeed:

```
insert into event (event_name, event_start, duration)
values ('First', timestamp '2017-10-16 10:00:00', interval '2' hour);

insert into event (event_start, duration)
values ('Second', timestamp '2017-10-16 12:00:00', interval '4' hour);
```

However the following insert will fail as the event "Third" overlaps with the event "Second":

```
insert into event (event_start, duration)
values ('Third', timestamp '2017-10-16 12:00:00', interval '1' hour);
```